# Perforce - Receiving error "Can't update committed change" when trying to append to change list description

Tags: perforce

In Perforce, I want to update and append some text information to an existing change-list *Description* that has already been submitted in the depot.

example of my text information:
**"[version 1.0]"**

I am trying do this through Perforce's **CLI**. I am using this command

> p4 -F Description="[version 1.0]" change -o 520760 | p4 change -i

But after executing this command I am receiving this error:

> Error in change specification. Can't update committed change 520760.

Is there something in the command that is invalid or am I missing anything additional to get this to work? Thanks.

Note: I looked at Perforce's documentation and see that they offer the "p4 change -f" command, but this requires an Admin or superuser privileges which I do not have.

Comment: Removed the tags `p4v`,  `perforce-client-spec`, `perforce-integrate`, and `perforce-stream` because none of those have anything to do with this question.  :)

Comment: @Sam Stafford ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you own the change, you can update the description with the `change -u` flag.  (You need the `change -f` command to update other people's changes, or to update fields other than the description.)

If you're doing this as a normal human being, no need to try to figure out how to write a clever shell script to do it.  Just run:

```
p4 change -u 520760
```

That will pop up an editor.  Make your edits, save, exit.  Easy!

If you need to execute this as not-a-human, I believe the syntax would be:

```
p4 --field "Description+=[version 1.0]" change -o 520760 | p4 change -iu
```

but I'm not actually positive that the `+=` will do what you want there; you might need to experiment.

Comment: - Yes, doing this for automation. I do not own the change unfortunately. I tried your command with "p4 change -if" but I receive "You don't have permission for this operation." Does this mean it cannot be done without getting either Admin or superuser rights?

Comment: Correct.  Your automation user will need to be granted admin rights to be able to mess with other users' submitted changelists.  Maybe an alternative approach would be a trigger that edits the description *before* it's submitted?

Comment: Thanks. Is the Admin the only one that can setup this trigger?

Comment: Yes, setting up a trigger requires **super** access since a trigger has direct access to the server machine and can mess with any in-flight command -- the trigger itself does not necessarily need to have admin/super user credentials though!  (For example, a trigger can just directly modify the text of a change description as it's saved, rather than running the `p4 change -f` command.)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help again.